# How do I perform a SelectMany in C# query syntax using a many-to-many joining table?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following c# statement that via EF generates exactly what I'm looking for but am curious as to how I'd write this with query syntax:

```
var dealers = this.Dealers
    .SelectMany (d => d.Brands, (d, col) => new { Name = d.Name, Brand = col.Name, StatusId = d.StatusId })
    .Where (d => d.StatusId == 1);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var dealers = from d in Dealers
              from col in d.Brands
              where d.StatusId == 1
              select new { Name = d.Name, 
                           Brand = col.Name, 
                           StatusId = d.StatusId };
```

Comment: the where clause should go above the select

Comment: Ugh..that's what I thought and when I did it in LinqPad I got an exception but it was because I mis-typed something. Thanks!